# ¿Como llamar a una función desde un módulo para que tenga efecto en otro en Python?

Tags: python

Resumiendo mi problema:

'a' es mi código principal.
'b' es un módulo importado en 'a' que abre una ventana independiente (vía Toplevel).
'x' es una función dentro de 'a'.

La cuestión es que quiero llamar a 'x' desde 'b' para que tenga efecto en 'a'

He metido a 'x' en un archivo independiente e importado en 'b', pero no sé como decirle que al ser llamada debe tener efecto en 'a' y no en 'b'.

Soy bastante nuevo en esto, por lo que es posible que la solución sea obvia y no la veo; pido perdón si es así.

Gracias.

P.D.: Utilizo Python 3.8, por si tiene influencia.

Comment: No sé si lo he entendido del todo bien, pero si has importado `b` en `a` y quieres que desde `b` se acceda a `a` para ejecutar `x` estarías haciendo una referencia cíclica, por lo que separar `x` es un primer paso necesario pero tu planteamiento no me encaja, porque lo que estás realizando al importar es crear una nueva referencia al módulo o función concreta por lo cual no estarían en el mismo ámbito. Puedes poner un ejemplo con código de qué es lo que esperas conseguir?

Comment: Quizá lo he querido resumir demasiado y no ha quedado claro. El programa (a) es una tabla construida a base de canvas que muestra los registros de una base de datos. 'b' abre una ventana que permite crear nuevos registros que se mostrarán en la tabla, y la función 'x' lo que hace es actualizar la pantalla para mostrar los nuevos registros. 'x' está asociada a un botón en 'a', pero lo que quiero es que cuando se cree un nuevo registro mediante 'b' se ejecute automáticamente la función 'x' para que se muestre en la tabla sin tener que hacerlo manualmente.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.